# How to remove string between two special characters in bash

Tags: linux, bash

Hi how can remove the words between two special characters in bash like from `/` to `|`

````
#cat demo.log| grep -i xenial-infra-security | awk '{print $1"|"$2}'
 libtiff5/**xenial-infra-security**|4.0.6-1ubuntu0.8+esm3
 tzdata/**xenial-infra-security,xenial-infra-security**|2022c-0ubuntu0.16.04+esm1```
````

Comment: `grep ... | awk ...` is an anti-pattern. Probably this could be done with a single `awk` (or `sed`) call. What are the lines containing the string `xenial-infra-security` in the file (demo.log) ?

Comment: Do you want to remove strings between special characters including special characters? Do the answer below help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can do it e.g. with `sed` as follows:

```bash
# Including special characters
echo "libtiff5/**xenial-infra-security**|4.0.6-1ubuntu0.8+esm3" | sed 's/\/\(.*\)|//g'
# Output: libtiff54.0.6-1ubuntu0.8+esm3

# Excluding special characters
echo "libtiff5/**xenial-infra-security**|4.0.6-1ubuntu0.8+esm3" | sed 's/\/\(.*\)|/\/|/g'
# Output: libtiff5/|4.0.6-1ubuntu0.8+esm3
```

or if you have your text in e.g. `file.txt`:

```bash
sed -e 's/\/\(.*\)|//g' -i file.txt
cat file.txt
# Output: 
# libtiff54.0.6-1ubuntu0.8+esm3
# tzdata2022c-0ubuntu0.16.04+esm1
```

P.S. If you want to **replace** the strings between two special charachters with e.g. `-` for readability:

```bash
echo "libtiff5/**xenial-infra-security**|4.0.6-1ubuntu0.8+esm3" | sed 's/\/\(.*\)|/-/g'
#Output: libtiff5-4.0.6-1ubuntu0.8+esm3
```